# I am using scapy to get probing information. I am new in python and also scapy

Tags: python, scapy

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *

ap_list = []

def PacketHandler(pkt) :

  if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :

            if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list :
                ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                print "AP MAC: %s with SSID: %s " %(pkt.addr2, pkt.info)


sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

using above code getting error

> no such device

Comment: What line is the error on? Do not respond here; [edit] your question.

Comment: Avoid placing personal information like "i'm new in XXX" in title  since it's useless

Comment: WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssid-sniffer-scapy-python.py", line 16, in <module>
    sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)

Comment: Well that’s pretty clear: the mon0 interface does not exist